Fourier Transform of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\cos(ax)$
I need to find Fourier Transform of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\cos(ax)$, I understand how Fourier Transform of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ looks like and how to find it, but I still have problems with solving my task.
When I get the following: $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\cos(ax)\cos(xy)}$, and then use exponents instead of cosines by Euler's formula, I get second power in exponent degree so it becomes impossible to integrate.

Use Euler's formula and complete the square in the exponent

@DanDan面, I got $e^{i(a-y)x-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ using Euler's formula, I guess there is no way to complete the square here

@JaneDoe: Try squaring the integral and using polar coordinates.

@JaneDoe I used the convolution theorem rather than completing the square.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

On your integrals, please include $dx$ or $dy$ or whatever.

Let $f(x)=e^{x^2/2}$ and $g(x)=\cos(ax)$.   We will find the Fourier Transform of $fg$ using the convolution theorem.

STEP $1$:  Fourier Transform of $f$
Note that $f\in L^1$, and hence we write its Fourier Transform as
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(y)&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}e^{ixy}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $y$ and integrating by parts reveals that
$$\frac{d}{dy}\mathscr{F}\{f\}(y)=-y\mathscr{F}\{f\}(y)\tag2$$
Solving the ODE in $(2)$ and noting that $\mathscr{F}\{f\}(0)=1$ yields
$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(y)=e^{-y^2/2}\tag3$$

STEP $2$:  Fourier Transform of $g$
The Fourier Transform of $g$ is a Tempered Disrtibution and given by
$$\mathscr{F}\{g\}(y)=\sqrt{\frac\pi 2}\left(\delta(y-|a|)+\delta(y+|a|)\right)$$

STEP $3$:  Convolve the Fourier Transforms of $f$ and $g$
Finally, we apply the convolution theorem to find that
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{fg\}(y)&=\frac1{\sqrt {2\pi}}\mathscr{F}\{f\}(y)*\mathscr{F}\{g\}(y)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(e^{-(y-|a|)^2/2}+e^{-(y+|a|)^2/2}\right)\\\\
&=e^{-(y^2+a^2)/2}\cosh(ay)
\end{align}$$

Note that we just need to complete the square in the exponentials, and then we can use the area of a Gaussian to finish off. We have the following:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \cos(ax) = \frac{1}{2}\left (e^{aix - \frac{x^2}{2}} + e^{-aix - \frac{x^2}{2}} \right )\\
\hat{f}(k) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left (\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(a + k)ix - \frac{x^2}{2}} \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-a + k)ix - \frac{x^2}{2}} \ \mathrm{d}x\right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left (e^{-\frac{1}{2}(a + k)^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x - (a + k)i)^2}\ \mathrm{d}x + e^{-\frac{1}{2}(-a + k)^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x - (-a + k)i)^2}\ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}x\right )\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} \left (e^{-\frac{1}{2}(a + k)^2} + e^{-\frac{1}{2}(-a + k)^2} \right )\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-\frac{a^2 + k^2}{2}} \cosh(ak) 
\end{align*}
Hence, the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is $\hat{f}(k) = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-\frac{a^2 + k^2}{2}} \cosh(ak)$.

Addendum: We used the fact that the Gaussian integral doesn't change upon translation in the complex plane. Indeed, we see:
\begin{align*}
I(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x + it)^2}{2}} \ \mathrm{d}x\\
I'(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty -i(x + it) e^{-\frac{(x + it)^2}{2}} \ \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \left [ie^{-\frac{(x + it)^2}{2}} \right ]_{-\infty}^\infty\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Hence, $I(t)$ is constant.

The Gaussian integral is $\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-x^2/2}, dx$.  You might want to show the result holds when the exponent doesn’t lie on the real axis, as in your solution.

@Aruralreader sure, included a proof of it

Others have already given you a concise answer for your particular question. I am just adding an answer for others who might have a similar, but not the same question. There is a general formula for Fourier Transform of $f(x) cos(ax)$ given by
$$F[f(x) cos(ax)](\omega) = \frac{\hat{f}(\omega-a)+\hat{f}(\omega+a)}{2}$$
Here, Fourier Transform is defined by
$$F[f(x)](\omega) = \hat{f}(\omega) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} dx$$
